# How to get description instead of coded value for a field with domain in hosted feature layer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, domains, arcgis-python-api

I have a hosted feature layer with a field with a domain (coded values).

How do I get the description instead of the coded value?

The layer is in the TOC of an aprx, and I can retrieve the domain name with `arcpy.ListFields(layer.dataSource, field)[0].domain` but that's just a string, I can't get its properties.
Also I don't think `arcpy.da.ListDomains()` applies to hosted feature layers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ArcGIS for Python API

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

## or use GIS("agol_url", "username", "password")
agol = GIS("home")

item = agol.content.get("FS_ITEM_ID")

## key: domain name, value: dictionary code:description
domains_dict = {}

## for each layer/table
## replace .layers with .tables to access tables instead
for lyr in item.layers:
    ## for each field in the layer/table
    for fld in lyr.properties.fields:
        ## if there is a coded domain
        if fld.domain and fld.domain.type == "codedValue":
            ## get the domain name
            domain_name = fld.domain.name
            ## this dictionary will represent the key as the code
            ## and the value as the description
            entry_dict = {}
            ## for each code value pair
            for entry in fld.domain.codedValues:
                for code, value in entry.items():
                    ## add them to the entry_dict
                    entry_dict[entry.code] = entry.name

            ## add to the domain_dict
            domains_dict[domain_name] = entry_dict

for name, codes in domains_dict.items():
    print(name, codes)
```